# Is there a more succinct way to have an html column all align=right?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-table

Is there a more succinct way to have an html table column align right besides putting `align="right"` on every single row?

Is there there any html or css where i can just specify it in one place to avoid the html on every single row?

```
<tr>
   <td align='right'>Col1</td>
   <td>Col2</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
   <td align='right'>Col1</td>
   <td>Col2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td align='right'>Col1</td>
   <td>Col2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td align='right'>Col1</td>
   <td>Col2</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Yes; use basic CSS classes.  (or learn about the `col` element)

Comment: Did you try the css `td { text-align: right; }`?

Comment: @Hidde that will make all `td` text to right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you will need is [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) or you can use [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child)

```
table tr td:first-child {
   text-align: right;
}
```

This will apply `text-align: right;` to each *first* `td` in each `tr`

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_alien/s3xDp/)</kbd>

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_alien/s3xDp/1/)</kbd> *(Nothing different, used `color` to indicate target elements)*

---

I am using general element selector here, so if you are going to target a single `table` it's better to declare `class` on the `table` and use a selector like

```
table.class_name tr td:first-child {
    /* Styles goes here */
}
```

Comment: Am using `:first-child` for greater compatibility as far as IE is concerned.

Comment: You can omit the _table tr_ part.

Comment: @Alohci maintaining the flow... \@salman that blinked me up later :-D

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS **pseudo Class Selector** ***nth-child(n)***

#### CSS

```
table tr td:nth-child(1) {
  text-align: right;
}
```

#### Check this <kbd>**[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3u3SD/179/)**</kbd>

---

#### CSS

```
table tr td {
  text-align: right;
}
```

#### Check this <kbd>**[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3u3SD/178/)**</kbd>

---

Use CSS **`text-align: right`** property,

```
<td class='rightside'>text to be aligned to right</td>

<style>
      .rightside{ text-align: right; }
</style>
```

Comment: how is that any better in terms of succinctness?